# Weak Power Hypothesis in ${\sf ZFC}$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

For sets $x, y$, let $x\approx y$ mean that there is a bijection $\varphi:x\to y$.
The *Weak Power Hypothesis (WPH)* states that

> if $x,y$ are sets and ${\cal P}(x)\approx {\cal P}(y)$ then $x\approx y$.

It appears to be [open](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-31/issue-3/The-dual-Cantor-Bernstein-theorem-and-the-partition-principle/10.1305/ndjfl/1093635502.full) whether (WPH) implies the Axiom of Choice or even the [Partition Principle](https://karagila.org/2014/on-the-partition-principle/).

**Question.** Is there a model of ${\sf ZFC}$ where (WPH) holds, but not (CH)?

Comment: Assuming you've spent enough time on this website asking questions related to GCH, you've surely come across Easton's theorem.

Comment: See Foreman, Woodin, Annals of Mathematics, 133 (1991), 1-35.